# mingw fatal error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, opengl, mingw

Trying to build binaries for https://github.com/memononen/nanovg with MinGW32, getting this error:

```
../example/example_gl2.c:21:23: fatal error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <GL/glew.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

What is the easiest/automated way to get all required MinGW dependencies in place?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding MinGW you already have everything in place. GLEW is a independently developed third party library which you have to install manually. A pretty new project is Win-Builds (http://win-builds.org/doku.php) which gives you a package manager for the installation of MinGW and an assortment of libraries. You could use that.

Or, if you want easier creation of redistributable Windows installations put the GLEW sources into your own project and build it together with your program.

Comment: Win-Builds looks promising, but I couldn't find GLEW there,

Comment: @techtonik: GLEW is easy enough to install manually. In fact I strongly recommend to simply slap it statically into your build.

Comment: It is probably easy if you code in C on Linux. Me is not. I want to play with it from Python.

Comment: @techtonik: If you want to use OpenGL from Python use `PyOpenGL` – there's no need to bother with GLEW when using Python, because `PyOpenGL`does all the extension/modern features loading for you. Heck you can even safely create a OpenGL context using C, make it current and call into Python code that uses PyOpenGL to draw stuff… and it works in the opposite direction as well (create window and OpenGL context using Python/PyOpenGL and let Python module implemented in C do the drawing – extended functionality must be loaded using the extension mechanism though).

Comment: I want to use NanoVG. OpenGL (and PyOpenGL FWIW) is beyond my mental abilities. I just want a surface where I can draw, click buttons, drag things etc. I would really like to skip all that pesky details that are so far from the things I want to accomplish.

Comment: @techtonik: Well then simply drop GLFW into th NanoVG source tree and make it build into NanoVG statically. Working with libraries and doing in-situ fixes like that are basic programmer housekeeping skills, so if you don't know already how to do it, it's a good time to start learning, as you'll need it quite a lot in the long run.

Comment: @techtonik:  Quick overview: If there's not yet a directory for 3rd party dependencies in the NanoVG source tree, add it. Copy the GLFW sources there and in the NanoVG build configuration add the GLFW include directoy to the project include configuration. Then add the GLFW sources to the list of compilation units (`.c` → `.o` compilation) so that GLFW gets built together with NanoVG. –– Personally I am of the opinion that every project should bring a full copy of all its prerequisites and build those if they're not available on the system. My bigger projects certainly do this.

Comment: Well, if you can add this description of manual process with some more detail, I will gladly accept it as an answer. The thing that bother me is that I can not detect where to place those files in project dir. Some instructions say that I need to install those development library files into my MinGW installation, and I'd really like to avoid polluting its global space with versions that may conflict, so this local setup for dependencies is very interesting.